# TexLive Installation fails on amstex, cannot create symlink

Tags: installing, linux, texlive-2017

I'm trying to install TexLive on GNU/Linux on x86_6 but the installation fails with the following comment:

```
Installing [0095/3495, time/total: 00:22/13:41]: amstex.x86_64-linux [1k]
tar: bin/x86_64-linux/amstex: Cannot create symlink to `pdftex': No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
untar: untarring /tmp/1FTqt8d27B/HUSZtHGP5u/amstex.x86_64-linux.tar failed (in /home/adipogen/tex)
TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
Installation failed.
```

I've downloaded the install-tl-folder via wget and run `./install-tl`. Because I don't have root access, I changed the folders to ones in my home directory.

I already tried to redownload and everything and restart  but it always fails here.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try with a portable installation? https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable

Comment: Can your user actually make symlinks? Never seen a user that could not... For testing you could choose the basic installation from the installer, then it does not have to run through 3500 packages each time you test this. I also install as myself even though I have root access (less damage)